# Microsoft Excel -> How to apply color Z to alternating rows, but only to those rows in which column X already has colour Y (via a formula or a macro)

Tags: microsoft-excel

So it is explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-color-to-alternate-rows-or-columns-30002ce0-7a1c-4d70-a70c-4b6232f09f5e) by Microsoft how to apply a colour (let's say color Z) to alternating rows, using a formula:

```
=MOD(ROW(),2)=0
```

However, what if we want to, in the **formula / or via a macro** as well (meaning: not via the 'manual' scope selection):

- only apply the alternating colouring (colour Z) of the rows to those rows (within the selection) in which column X already has colour Y ('already' implying: before the application of the alternating colouring formula)

Comment: And colour Y is applied from conditional formatting?

Comment: @BigBen No, colour Y was already applied manually beforehand.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done with conditional formatting (or if it can, not sure if it'd be reliable).

Comment: @BigBen There should be a way to check right? ---
If column X is of colour Y → Do not apply alternating colouring. --- If column X is not of colour Y → Do apply alternating colouring.

Comment: Not with a formula. You can't really determine the color of a cell with a formula... so you can't build a conditional formatting rule to do this.

Comment: @bigben With 'determine' you mean check the existing colour, or apply a new (alternating) colour?

Comment: Could there be a way via macro then?

Comment: "Check the existing colour". You could achieve the end result with a macro probably, yes. `Range.Interior.Color` would get you the existing colour and would also be used to apply a new alternating colour.

Comment: @BigBen I would be interested in such a macro. I am hoping for a result that would have the features above, combined with the feature of NOT colouring a certain column (as per your answer to another OP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63744503/4367046).

Comment: Create a helper column called 'Colour_Y'. Apply a filter to your data. Filter by color. Populate the helper column with ticks for all rows in which column X has color Y. Incorporate `NOT(ISBLANK([Colour_Y]))` into your conditional formatting formula. Bob's your uncle.

Comment: @AlexM put that as an answer it could be really useful

Comment: @PeterH Too lazy to write it up properly. Plus I'm horrible with conditional formatting. Feel free to have a go yourself; @ me if you do and I'll upvote!